# How to divided number into three continuous parts such that the third part is the sum of the other two?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a python program to determine if the digits of a number can be divided into three continuous parts such that the third part is the sum of the other two. e.g. 9999198 can be divided because 99 + 99 = 198. 
The sum will always be the least significant digit.
I am unable to come with approach please help.

I am trying to implement it as treating a digit as a single number like in the above case a 7. Then trying to create all subset of three number which adds to 7 and then use these subsets to find the right one. Like 7 = 2,2,3 so my answer is 99,99,198.

My problem is that how can we efficiently split these number into a subset of 3 number.

Comment: Did you have a *question*? This isn't a code writing service.

Comment: Did you try to do it? If yes please let us know where are you stuck?

Comment: Sorry, yes I have a question. I am stuck on how to approach this problem.

Comment: That's not really a question, and certainly not on topic here. See [ask].

Comment: @SanchitKumar , I am unable to come with an approach.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Please go through my edit . I rectify my mistake.

Comment: That still isn't a question. See e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3001761. You should at least *attempt* your own homework before posting here.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I did and if I can't come with any approach how I am able to post my sol here.

Comment: The point is that if you can't come up with any approach than *you don't have a valid question here*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I added my approach, now please leave me alone.

Comment: But you don't have any *code*. This site is for programming Q&A, not general problem solving advice. I'd recommend taking the [tour] and spending some time in the [help].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's my solution, it checks all possible combinations of splitting given number in 3 parts and checks whether sum of first two components are equal the third one.

```
def correct_number(x):
    str_nmbr = str(x)
    for result_split in range(len(str_nmbr)-2):
        part_3 = int(str_nmbr[-result_split-1:])

        for components_split in range(len(str_nmbr)-2-result_split):
            part_2 = int(str_nmbr[1+components_split: -result_split-1])
            part_1 = int(str_nmbr[:components_split+1])

            if part_1 + part_2 == part_3:
                return True

    return False

print(correct_number(9999198)) # True
```

As author requested here's visual explanation how determining parts for number works, given number "1234567"

**1 2 3 4 5 6 7:**

- First loop chooses second separator
- 1 2 3 4 5 6|7
- Second loop chooses first one
- 1 2|3 4 5 6|7
- 1 2 3|4 5 6|7
- 1 2 3 4|5 6|7
- 1 2 3 4 5|6|7
- . . . Then we move second second separator 1 step back
- 1 2 3 4 5|6 7
- And we continue on moving first separator
- 1|2 3 4 5|6 7
- 1 2|3 4 5|6 7
- 1 2 3|4 5|6 7
- . . .

Comment: @Looioe Thanx for the sol. can u explain the little bit how to print all possible 3 number combination? Like 7 into 2,2,3 and 1,3,3 and so on . I guess you use the same approach.

Comment: Also FYI [*What is a help vampire?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire)

Comment: @user7390332 first loop determines place where we split number into components side and result side for example with number of 7 digits we'd have to split it from 2 to the end (2 because we need at least 2 digits for first components). Second loop finds separator for components, we want it to be from 1 to place where starts our result number - 1. It would look like this:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7:
First loop chooses second separator
1|2 3 4 5 6|7
1 2|3 4 5 6|7
1 2 3|4 5 6|7
. . .